# Android Facebook App Security error There are problems with the security certificate for this site

Tags: android, facebook

When links to our site are posted on facebook. Some users get this error when viewing the link in the Android Facebook Browser.  Our SSL is current and active. And it does not happen on desktop browsers or in the ios Facebook App. We are not doing anything hinky, or spamy. Its a quiz web app.

"Security error There are problems with the security certificate for this site"

What can we do to stop this from happening?

Here is the link creating the error. It is a web application for fan interaction during events.

http://static.shout.tv/html5app/?aM=S&t=r&aI=2&lc=en

Comment: same problem here, did you find a solution to this issue ?